Video is not compressed with ffmpeg
I wrote a wrapper for JNI in cpp language to compress the video:
#include <iostream>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <jni.h>

extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/log.h>
#include <libavutil/time.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

using namespace std;

#define LOG_TAG "VideoNative"
#define LOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define LOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)


#define FFMPEG_LOG_TAG "FFMPEG_VideoNative"
#define FLOGD(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, FFMPEG_LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FLOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, FFMPEG_LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)
#define FLOGE(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, FFMPEG_LOG_TAG, __VA_ARGS__)


AVFormatContext *initInputFormatContext(const char *path);

AVFormatContext *initOutputFormatContext(const char *path);

void copyAvFormatContext(AVFormatContext **inputContext, AVFormatContext **outputContext);


void writeFileHeader(AVFormatContext *formatContext);

static void ffmpeg_log_callback(void *ptr, int level, const char *fmt, va_list vargs) {
    if (level <= av_log_get_level()) {
        char log_buffer[1024];
        vsnprintf(log_buffer, sizeof(log_buffer), fmt, vargs);

        switch (level) {
            case AV_LOG_DEBUG:
                FLOGD("%s", log_buffer);
                break;
            case AV_LOG_WARNING:
            case AV_LOG_ERROR:
            case AV_LOG_FATAL:
                FLOGE("%s", log_buffer);
                break;
            default:
                FLOGI("%s", log_buffer);
                break;
        }
    }
}


void compress(const char *inputPath, const char *outputPath) {
    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_TRACE);
    av_log_set_callback(ffmpeg_log_callback);

    AVFormatContext *inputFormatContext = initInputFormatContext(inputPath);
    if (!inputFormatContext) {
        LOGE("input format context fail");
        return;
    }
    AVFormatContext *outputFormatContext = initOutputFormatContext(outputPath);
    if (!outputFormatContext) {
        LOGE("output format context fail");
        return;
    }

    copyAvFormatContext(&inputFormatContext, &outputFormatContext);

    if (avio_open2(&outputFormatContext->pb, outputPath, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE, nullptr, nullptr) < 0) {
        LOGE("error to open file");
    }

    writeFileHeader(outputFormatContext);

    AVPacket *inputPaket = av_packet_alloc();
    if (!inputPaket) {
        LOGE("packet not find");
    }
    while (av_read_frame(inputFormatContext, inputPaket) >= 0) {
        if (av_interleaved_write_frame(outputFormatContext, inputPaket) < 0) {
            LOGE("can not write frame");
        }
    }

    if (av_write_trailer(outputFormatContext) < 0) {
        LOGE("can not write trailer");
    }
}

void writeFileHeader(AVFormatContext *formatContext) {
    AVDictionary *option = nullptr;
    if (avformat_write_header(formatContext, &option) < 0) {
        LOGE("write header fail");
        return;
    }
    av_dict_free(&option);
}


void copyAvFormatContext(AVFormatContext **inputContext, AVFormatContext **outputContext) {
    int numStream = static_cast<int>((*inputContext)->nb_streams);
    for (int i = 0; i < numStream; i++) {
        AVStream *inputStream = (*inputContext)->streams[i];
        AVCodecParameters *inputCodecParams = inputStream->codecpar;
        AVCodec *outputCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(inputCodecParams->codec_id);
        AVStream *outputStream = avformat_new_stream(*outputContext, outputCodec);
        AVCodecContext *codecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(outputCodec);
        codecContext->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
        av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "crf", "30", 0);
        av_opt_set(codecContext->priv_data, "movflags", "faststart", 0);

        if (avcodec_parameters_from_context(outputStream->codecpar, codecContext) < 0) {
            LOGE("cant set option" );
        }
        AVCodecParameters *outputCodecParams = outputStream->codecpar;
        avcodec_parameters_copy(outputCodecParams, inputCodecParams);
    }
}

AVFormatContext *initOutputFormatContext(const char *path) {
    AVFormatContext *formatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(&formatContext, nullptr, "mp4", path) < 0) {
        LOGE("open output fail");
        return nullptr;
    }
    return formatContext;
}


AVFormatContext *initInputFormatContext(const char *path) {
    AVFormatContext *formatContext = avformat_alloc_context();
    if (avformat_open_input(&formatContext, path, nullptr, nullptr) != 0) {
        LOGE("open input fail");
        return nullptr;
    }
    if (avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, nullptr) < 0) {
        LOGE("stream fail");
        return nullptr;
    }
    return formatContext;
}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_ir_nasim_core_modules_file_FileNativeLoader_compressFile(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                              jstring input_path,
                                                              jstring output_path) {
    compress(env->GetStringUTFChars(input_path, JNI_FALSE),
             env->GetStringUTFChars(output_path, JNI_FALSE));
    return 0;
}

...but the compression did not happen and the output video is exactly the same as the input video.

Nothing about your problem is specific to JNI or Android. Removed the JNI and Android tags.

I was able to write the code
#include <iostream>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/opt.h>
#include <libavutil/log.h>
#include <libavutil/time.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}

using namespace std;

enum class ResultState {
    SUCCESS = 1,
    FAILED = 0
};

typedef struct StreamContext {
    AVCodecContext *decodeContext;
    AVCodecContext *encodeContext;
} StreamContext;

struct StreamTask {
    std::atomic<bool> cancelled;
    StreamContext streamContext;
};

JNIEnv *environment;
static jobject callbackJObject;
static jclass callbackJClass;
static jmethodID logCallbackMethodId;
static jmethodID ProgressCallbackMethodId;


std::shared_ptr<StreamTask> currentTask;


AVFormatContext *initInputFormatContext(const char *path);

AVFormatContext *initOutputFormatContext(const char *path);

ResultState copyAvFormatContext(AVFormatContext *inputContext, AVFormatContext *outputContext,
                                StreamContext *streamContext);

void writeFileHeader(AVFormatContext *formatContext);

ResultState compress(const char *inputPath, const char *outputPath, std::shared_ptr<StreamTask> task);

void initCallbacks(jobject callback);

void logCallBack(const string &logMessage);

void progressCallBack(int amountOfProgress);


extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_ir_nasim_core_modules_file_FfmpegCompressor_compressFile(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                              jstring inputPath,
                                                              jstring outputPath,
                                                              jobject callback) {
    currentTask = std::make_shared<StreamTask>();
    currentTask->cancelled = false;
    environment = env;
    initCallbacks(callback);

    logCallBack("Start video compression");

    try {
        if (compress(environment->GetStringUTFChars(inputPath, JNI_FALSE),
                     environment->GetStringUTFChars(outputPath, JNI_FALSE), currentTask) ==
            ResultState::FAILED) {
            logCallBack("Video compression failed");
            return static_cast<jint>(ResultState::FAILED);
        }
    } catch (...) {
        logCallBack("Video compression failed (exception)");
        return static_cast<jint>(ResultState::FAILED);
    }

    progressCallBack(100);
    logCallBack("Video compression successful");
    return static_cast<jint>(ResultState::SUCCESS);
}

void initCallbacks(jobject callback) {
    callbackJObject = callback;
    callbackJClass = environment->GetObjectClass(callbackJObject);
    const char *logCallbackName = "logCallBack";
    const char *logCallbackSignature = "(Ljava/lang/String;)V";
    logCallbackMethodId = environment->GetMethodID(callbackJClass, logCallbackName,
                                                   logCallbackSignature);

    const char *progressCallbackName = "progressCallBack";
    const char *progressCallbackSignature = "(I)V";
    ProgressCallbackMethodId = environment->GetMethodID(callbackJClass, progressCallbackName,
                                                        progressCallbackSignature);
}

ResultState compress(const char *inputPath, const char *outputPath,  std::shared_ptr<StreamTask> task) {
    AVFormatContext *inputContext = initInputFormatContext(inputPath);
    if (!inputContext) {
        logCallBack("Failed to initialize input format context");
        return ResultState::FAILED;
    }

    AVFormatContext *outputContext = initOutputFormatContext(outputPath);
    if (!outputContext) {
        logCallBack("Failed to initialize output format context");
        avformat_close_input(&inputContext);
        return ResultState::FAILED;
    }

    auto *streamContext = (StreamContext *) av_mallocz_array(inputContext->nb_streams,
                                                             sizeof(StreamContext));
    if (!streamContext) {
        logCallBack("Could not allocate stream context");
        avformat_close_input(&inputContext);
        avformat_free_context(outputContext);
        return ResultState::FAILED;
    }

    if (copyAvFormatContext(inputContext, outputContext, streamContext) == ResultState::FAILED) {
        logCallBack("Failed to copy format context");
        avformat_close_input(&inputContext);
        avformat_free_context(outputContext);
        av_free(streamContext);
        return ResultState::FAILED;
    }

    writeFileHeader(outputContext);

    auto totalFileSize = static_cast<off_t >(avio_size(inputContext->pb));
    off_t processedBytes = 0;

    AVPacket packet;
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();


    while (av_read_frame(inputContext, &packet) >= 0) {
        if (task->cancelled) return ResultState::FAILED;
        AVStream *inputStream = inputContext->streams[packet.stream_index];
        AVStream *outputStream = outputContext->streams[packet.stream_index];

        processedBytes += packet.size;
        int progressPercentage = (processedBytes * 100) / totalFileSize;
        progressCallBack(progressPercentage);


        if (inputStream->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {

            AVCodecContext *decodeContext = streamContext[packet.stream_index].decodeContext;
            int ret = avcodec_send_packet(decodeContext, &packet);
            if (ret < 0) {
                logCallBack("Error sending packet for decoding");
                break;
            }

            while (ret >= 0) {
                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(decodeContext, frame);
                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                    break;
                else if (ret < 0) {
                    logCallBack("Error during decoding");
                    break;
                }

                AVCodecContext *encodeContext = streamContext[packet.stream_index].encodeContext;
                frame->pts = frame->best_effort_timestamp;
                ret = avcodec_send_frame(encodeContext, frame);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    logCallBack("Error sending frame for encoding");
                    break;
                }
                while (true) {
                    AVPacket encodePacket;
                    av_init_packet(&encodePacket);
                    ret = avcodec_receive_packet(encodeContext, &encodePacket);
                    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                        break;
                    else if (ret < 0) {
                        logCallBack("Error during encoding");
                        break;
                    }

                    av_packet_rescale_ts(&encodePacket, encodeContext->time_base,
                                         outputStream->time_base);
                    encodePacket.stream_index = packet.stream_index;

                    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(outputContext, &encodePacket);
                    av_packet_unref(&encodePacket);
                    if (ret < 0) {
                        logCallBack("Error writing frame");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                av_frame_unref(frame);
            }
        } else if (inputStream->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO ||
                   inputStream->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE) {

            packet.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(packet.pts, inputStream->time_base,
                                          outputStream->time_base,
                                          (AVRounding) (AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
            packet.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(packet.dts, inputStream->time_base,
                                          outputStream->time_base,
                                          (AVRounding) (AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX));
            packet.duration = av_rescale_q(packet.duration, inputStream->time_base,
                                           outputStream->time_base);
            packet.pos = -1;
            packet.stream_index = packet.stream_index;

            if (av_interleaved_write_frame(outputContext, &packet) < 0) {
                logCallBack("Error writing packet");
                break;
            }
            av_packet_unref(&packet);
        } else {
            av_packet_unref(&packet);
        }
    }

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inputContext->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (streamContext[i].encodeContext) {
            AVCodecContext *encodeContext = streamContext[i].encodeContext;
            int ret = avcodec_send_frame(encodeContext, nullptr);
            while (ret >= 0) {
                AVPacket encodePacket;
                av_init_packet(&encodePacket);
                ret = avcodec_receive_packet(encodeContext, &encodePacket);
                if (ret == AVERROR_EOF || ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN))
                    break;
                else if (ret < 0) {
                    logCallBack("Error during encoding");
                    break;
                }

                AVStream *outputStream = outputContext->streams[i];
                av_packet_rescale_ts(&encodePacket, encodeContext->time_base,
                                     outputStream->time_base);
                encodePacket.stream_index = static_cast<int>(i);


                ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(outputContext, &encodePacket);
                av_packet_unref(&encodePacket);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    logCallBack("Error writing frame");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    av_write_trailer(outputContext);


    av_frame_free(&frame);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inputContext->nb_streams; i++) {
        if (streamContext[i].decodeContext)
            avcodec_free_context(&streamContext[i].decodeContext);
        if (streamContext[i].decodeContext)
            avcodec_free_context(&streamContext[i].decodeContext);
    }

    av_free(streamContext);

    avformat_close_input(&inputContext);

    if (!(outputContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        avio_closep(&outputContext->pb);

    avformat_free_context(outputContext);
    return ResultState::SUCCESS;
}

AVFormatContext *initInputFormatContext(const char *path) {
    AVFormatContext *formatContext = nullptr;
    if (avformat_open_input(&formatContext, path, nullptr, nullptr) < 0) {
        logCallBack("Could not open input file");
        return nullptr;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(formatContext, nullptr) < 0) {
        logCallBack("Failed to retrieve input stream information");
        avformat_close_input(&formatContext);
        return nullptr;
    }

    return formatContext;
}


AVFormatContext *initOutputFormatContext(const char *path) {
    AVFormatContext *formatContext = nullptr;
    if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(&formatContext, nullptr, nullptr, path) < 0) {
        logCallBack("Could not create output context");
        return nullptr;
    }
    return formatContext;
}


ResultState copyAvFormatContext(AVFormatContext *inputContext, AVFormatContext *outputContext,
                                StreamContext *streamContext) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < inputContext->nb_streams; i++) {
        AVStream *inputStream = inputContext->streams[i];
        AVCodecParameters *inputCodecParameters = inputStream->codecpar;

        AVStream *outputStream = avformat_new_stream(outputContext, nullptr);
        if (!outputStream) {
            logCallBack("Failed allocating output stream");
            return ResultState::FAILED;
        }

        if (inputCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            AVCodec *decoder = avcodec_find_decoder(inputCodecParameters->codec_id);
            if (!decoder) {
                logCallBack("Failed to find decoder for stream");
                return ResultState::FAILED;
            }
            AVCodecContext *decodeContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(decoder);
            if (!decodeContext) {
                logCallBack("Failed to allocate the decoder context for stream");
                return ResultState::FAILED;
            }
            if (avcodec_parameters_to_context(decodeContext, inputCodecParameters) < 0) {
                logCallBack(
                        "Failed to copy decoder parameters to input decoder context for stream");
                return ResultState::FAILED;
            }

            if (avcodec_open2(decodeContext, decoder, nullptr) < 0) {
                logCallBack("Failed to open decoder for stream");
                return ResultState::FAILED;
            }
            streamContext[i].decodeContext = decodeContext;


            AVCodec *encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
            if (!encoder) {
                logCallBack("Necessary encoder not found");
                return ResultState::FAILED;
            }

            AVCodecContext *encoderContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
            if (!encoderContext) {
                logCallBack("Failed to allocate the encoder context");
                return ResultState::FAILED;
            }


            encoderContext->height = decodeContext->height;
            encoderContext->width = decodeContext->width;
            encoderContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
            encoderContext->time_base = inputStream->time_base;

            av_opt_set(encoderContext->priv_data, "crf", "30", 0);

            if (outputContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
                encoderContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

            if (avcodec_open2(encoderContext, encoder, nullptr) < 0) {
                logCallBack("Cannot open video encoder for stream");
                return ResultState::FAILED;
            }
            streamContext[i].encodeContext = encoderContext;

            if (avcodec_parameters_from_context(outputStream->codecpar, encoderContext) < 0) {
                logCallBack("Failed to copy encoder parameters to output stream");
                return ResultState::FAILED;
            }

            outputStream->time_base = encoderContext->time_base;

        } else if (inputCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO ||
                   inputCodecParameters->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE) {

            if (avcodec_parameters_copy(outputStream->codecpar, inputCodecParameters) < 0) {
                logCallBack("Failed to copy codec parameters from input to output stream");
                return ResultState::FAILED;
            }
            outputStream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
            outputStream->time_base = inputStream->time_base;
        } else {
            logCallBack("Stream is not an audio or video stream and will be ignored");
        }
    }
    return ResultState::SUCCESS;
}

void writeFileHeader(AVFormatContext *formatContext) {
    if (!(formatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (avio_open(&formatContext->pb, formatContext->url, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE) < 0) {
            logCallBack("Could not open output file");
            return;
        }
    }

    AVDictionary *opts = nullptr;
    av_dict_set(&opts, "movflags", "faststart", 0);

    if (avformat_write_header(formatContext, &opts) < 0) {
        logCallBack("Error occurred when opening output file");
        return;
    }
    av_dict_free(&opts);
}

void logCallBack(const string &logMessage) {
    jstring jLogMessage = environment->NewStringUTF(logMessage.c_str());

    environment->CallVoidMethod(callbackJObject, logCallbackMethodId, jLogMessage);
    environment->DeleteLocalRef(jLogMessage);
}

void progressCallBack(int amountOfProgress) {
    environment->CallVoidMethod(callbackJObject, ProgressCallbackMethodId, amountOfProgress);
}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_ir_nasim_core_modules_file_FfmpegCompressor_cancel(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    if (currentTask) {
        currentTask->cancelled = true;
    }
}

